# When did Old Slavic ЪI become Ы?

Tags: slavic-languages

When did Old Slavic ЪI become Ы?

Comment: While the question is a bit terse and doesn't show evidence of research, I don't necessarily see the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: @jogloran Not showing evidence of research is the canonical reason for downvoting. There's no good reason for the close votes, though.

Comment: @Cairnarvon In terms of not demonstrating evidence of research, I don't see this question as being any worse than (e.g.) https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/38682/can-you-rhyme-words-in-sign-language, which has 23 upvotes and counting. The only difference is the terseness, which is not a rules violation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question would be better asked as “When did the OCS **ЪИ** become **ЪІ** and when did **ЪІ** become **Ы**?” The three variants were originally used interchangeably, but later **Ы** took over, the most obvious reasons being it had the simplest shape of the three and since the yers disappeared as sounds it became irrelevant which one to use, **ЪІ** or **Ы**.

The first dated Cyrillic printed book *Octoechos*, 1491, in Kraków, by [Schweipolt Fiol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweipolt_Fiol), had the letter as **Ы**, and since then all the printed Cyrillic books followed that trend. You can see lots of Ыs in [this spread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweipolt_Fiol#/media/File:Schweipolt_Fiol%27s_Octoechos.jpg) from the Octoechos, the first one is about the middle of the top line of the left page:

[image]

So the answer to your question is: by the end of the 15th century AD **Ы** became the only one.